# Soma de 2 variáveis na Estrutura de repetição While

Tags: python, variáveis, while

Erro na linha 11:

```
senha = int(input("senha: "))  
contrasenha = int(input("Contra senha: "))  

x = senha + contrasenha

while (x != 20):
    print("ACESSO NEGADO")
    contrasenha = int(input("Contra senha: ")) #Essa linha não está somando com o valor de senha

if (x == 20):
    print("ACESSO LIBERADO")
```

Como faço pra variável (contrasenha) somar com a variável (soma) e não ficar no loop infinito ?

Link GitHub: https://github.com/MatheusDls/Exercise-2-While-

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu código não está somando porque o loop está pedindo contrasenha novamente, mas não está realizando a soma com o novo valor.

Seu código deveria ser assim:

```
senha = int(input("senha: "))  
contrasenha = int(input("Contra senha: "))  

x = senha + contrasenha

while (x != 20):
    print("ACESSO NEGADO")
    contrasenha = int(input("Contra senha: ")) #Essa linha não está somando 
com o valor de senha
    x = senha + contrasenha #adicionado

if (x == 20):
    print("ACESSO LIBERADO")
```

Comment: Deu certo ! obrigado !